# What is the word starting with P that is a type of chart where all values are calculated?

Tags: single-word-requests

So, it is a word that that is used with 'analysis' and it means to calculate using all possible values to prepare a chart (I only know this meaning, it is not the dictionary meaning). Let me give you a background:
E.g. In a case study, I have a window size of 2x3. Now, I have been asked to calculate the different properties for all varying possible sizes. e.g 3x3, 3x4, 3x5, 2x4, 2x5, 3x2, etc. And then to prepare a table. What is this type of analysis called?

Comment: You’re probably thinking of ***permutations***.

Comment: no, it is not permutations, because 'permutation analysis' does not fit. Thank you though, I can still use it.

Comment: what do you mean “doesn’t fit”? Are you doing a crossword?

Comment: when I said it does not fit, I meant that the two words 'permutation' and 'analysis', when used together, do not form the meaning that I am looking for.

Answer (score 2):

I think the word you're looking for is

> Permutations

It is a mathematical term used in Probability.

Here are the definitions:
[Permutation wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Permutation)

[Permutation dictionary.com](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/permutation)

Not to be confused with ['Combinations'](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Combination)